# C# Printing with PrintTicket and Locked Printing

Tags: c#, xml, system.printing

I am trying to print a document from one of our Applications which is located on a servers.
The application is based on C# .Net Framework 4.7.2.
To perform the printing, I want to use the PrintTicket, because we need to edit some settings.

My problem concerns the Secure Printing (Locked Printing). I don't know exactly how to configure this. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/sample-printticket-file-for-pin-printing)

I have managed to edit the XML configuration so that a PIN can be set.
However, nothing happens in the transmission to the printer afterwards.

My approach so far:

```
private (string printerName, PrintTicket printTicket) GetPrintOptions(string printerName, int tray)
        {
            // Get the dictionary of print queues that the print server hosts.
            var printQueues = WpfPrinterUtilities.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
            // Select the print queue.
            var printQueue = printQueues.First(p => p.Value.FullName.Contains(printerName)).Value;
            // Retrieve the dictionary of input bins from the print queue configuration.
            var inputBins = WpfPrinterUtilities.GetInputBins(printQueue);
            // Get the default print ticket associated with the print queue.
            var printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;

            if (inputBins.Any())
            {
                string trayname = string.Empty;
                if (inputBins.ContainsKey($"Tray {tray}"))
                {
                    trayname = $"Tray {tray}";
                }
                else
                {
                    trayname = $"Fach {tray}";
                }

                // Modify a print ticket input bin value.
                printTicket = WpfPrinterUtilities.ModifyPrintTicket(printTicket, "psk:JobInputBin", inputBins[trayname]);
                //printTicket = WpfPrinterUtilities.ModifyPrintTicket(printTicket, "psk11:JobPasscode", "psk:On");
                //printTicket = WpfPrinterUtilities.ModifyPrintTicket(printTicket, "psk11:JobPasscodeString", "123456");
            }

            return (printQueue.FullName, printTicket);
        }



public static PrintTicket ModifyPrintTicket(PrintTicket ticket, string featureName, string newValue)
        {
            if (ticket == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ticket");

            // Read Xml of the PrintTicket xml.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(ticket.GetXmlStream());

            // Create NamespaceManager and add PrintSchemaFrameWork-Namespace hinzufugen (should be on DocumentElement of the PrintTicket).
            // Prefix: psf NameSpace: xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework"
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Prefix, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
            manager.AddNamespace("xsi", "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            manager.AddNamespace("xsd", "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            manager.AddNamespace("psk", "https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords");
            manager.AddNamespace("pskv11", "https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2013/05/printing/printschemakeywordsv11");

            // Search node with desired feature we're looking for and set newValue for it
            string xpath = string.Format("//psf:Feature[@name='{0}']/psf:Option", featureName);
            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, manager);
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["name"].Value != newValue)
                    node.Attributes["name"].Value = newValue;
            }

            XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            CreatePasscodeStringNode().ForEach(n => root.AppendChild(root.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(n, true)));


            // Create a new PrintTicket out of the XML.
            PrintTicket modifiedPrintTicket = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                modifiedPrintTicket = new PrintTicket(stream);
            }

            return modifiedPrintTicket;
        }

private static List<XmlNode> CreatePasscodeStringNode()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var xml = @"<Root xmlns:psf=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework"" " +
                    @"xmlns:xsi=""https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " +
                    @"xmlns:xsd=""https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" version=""1"" " +
                    @"xmlns:psk=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords"" " +
                    @"xmlns:pskv11=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2013/05/printing/printschemakeywordsv11""> " +
                    @"<psf:ParameterInit name=""pskv11:JobPasscodeString""><psf:Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"">123456</psf:Value></psf:ParameterInit><psf:Feature name=""pskv11:JobPasscode""><psf:Option name=""psk:On"" /></psf:Feature></Root>";

            xmlDoc.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(xml));


            //XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            //XmlElement n = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ParameterInit");
            //n.Prefix = "psf";
            //n.SetAttribute("name", "pskv11:JobPasscodeString");

            //XmlElement n2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Value");
            //n2.Prefix = "psf";
            //n2.SetAttribute("xsi:type", "xsd:string");
            //n2.InnerText = "123456";

            //n.AppendChild(n2);

            var result = new List<XmlNode>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                result.Add(node);
            return result;
        }
```

What am I missing?
The XML is formated correctly (see below) and can be transmited to the printer, but nothing happens.

```
<psf:PrintTicket xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:psk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemakeywords" xmlns:ns0000="http://schemas.ricoh.com/2007/printing/keywords" version="1">
    <psf:ParameterInit name="ns0000:PageDevmodeSnapshot">
        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value xxx</psf:Value>
    </psf:ParameterInit>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageOverlayWatermark">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobBannerPage">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:BannerPageInputBin">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:AUTO"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:BannerPageMediaType">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Standard_Recycled"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageResolution">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:_2400x600">
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:ResolutionX">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">600</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:ResolutionY">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">600</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
        </psf:Option>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobRicPrintJob">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:RicPrintNormal"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:ScheduledPrint">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageOutputColor">
        <psf:Option name="psk:Color"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:DocumentCollate">
        <psf:Option name="psk:Uncollated"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobOffset">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Normal"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobNUpAllDocumentsContiguously">
        <psf:Option>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:PagesPerSheet">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
        </psf:Option>
        <psf:Feature name="psk:PresentationDirection">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:None"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:Frame">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobBlackOverPrint">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDuplexModeOneSidedPrint">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobSecretNumbering">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:SecretNumberingSize">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Middle"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:SecretNumberingDensity">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Middle"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:SecretNumberingColor">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Black"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobFold">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:ParameterInit name="ns0000:JobTrackID">
        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
    </psf:ParameterInit>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobWhitePaperSuppress">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobBooklet">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:BookletPageOrder">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:OpenToLeftOrTop"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobStapleAllDocuments">
        <psf:Option name="psk:None"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PagePrintPaperSize">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:SameAsPageMediaSize"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageColorProfileForPhoto">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Photographic"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageHeaderFooter">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterPrintPer">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:OriginalPage"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterDate">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterDatePosition">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:TopLeft"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterDateFormat">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:YYYYMMDD_DotFormat"/>
            </psf:Feature>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterNumber">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterNumberPosition">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:BottomCenter"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterNumberFormat">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:OnlyNumber"/>
            </psf:Feature>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterText">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterTextPosition">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:BottomLeft"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:HeaderFooterTextFormat">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:FileName"/>
            </psf:Feature>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobColorUniversalDesign">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDuplexAllDocumentsDirection">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:LongEdgeLeftOrTop"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously">
        <psf:Option name="psk:TwoSidedLongEdge"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDitherForGraphics">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Photographic"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobCopyGuard">
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardText">
            <psf:Option>
                <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyGuardTextString">
                    <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">COPY</psf:Value>
                </psf:ScoredProperty>
                <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyGuardFontSize">
                    <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">70</psf:Value>
                </psf:ScoredProperty>
            </psf:Option>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardTextFont">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:NimbusSans_Bold"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardTextPosition">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:Center">
                    <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyGuardTextAngle">
                        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">30</psf:Value>
                    </psf:ScoredProperty>
                </psf:Option>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardTextType">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:UserDefined"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardRepeatedText">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:Repeat">
                    <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyGuardLineSpace">
                        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">70</psf:Value>
                    </psf:ScoredProperty>
                </psf:Option>
            </psf:Feature>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyGuardPatternEffects">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Normal"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDither">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Auto"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDitheringSelectObject">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:SetAllObject"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:ParameterInit name="psk:JobCopiesAllDocuments">
        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</psf:Value>
    </psf:ParameterInit>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageOrientation">
        <psf:Option name="psk:Portrait"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PagePhotoPrintingIntent">
        <psf:Option name="psk:PhotoDraft"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobCoverFront">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:NoCover"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CoverFrontInputBin">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Tray1"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageColorProfileForGraphics">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Presentation"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobChapterPrint">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageColorProfileForText">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Text"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobLetterheadMode">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:PrinterDefault"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageScaling">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:FitToPaperSize"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobOutputBin">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:PrinterDefault"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PagePoster">
        <psf:Option>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:SheetsPerPage">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
        </psf:Option>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobCopyControlPrint">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:DocumentCollateDistribution">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:PrinterCollate"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageMediaSize">
        <psf:Option name="psk:ISOA4">
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:MediaSizeWidth">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">210000</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:MediaSizeHeight">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">297000</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
        </psf:Option>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobFixdmColor">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageImageWatermark">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageColorProfile">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Auto"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobCoverBack">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:NoCover"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CoverBackInputBin">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Tray1"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobInputBin">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Tray1"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobPrintDensity">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobPrintTextAsBlack">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobGraphicsMode">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Vector"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobPageOrder">
        <psf:Option name="psk:Standard"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDitherForPhoto">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Photographic"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobDitherForText">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Text"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobGrayReproduction">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:BlackForAllObjects"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobBalanceAdjustment">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:SetAllObject">
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:BrightnessAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:ContrastAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:SaturationAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:ColorBalanceRAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:ColorBalanceGAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
            <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:ColorBalanceBAll">
                <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</psf:Value>
            </psf:ScoredProperty>
        </psf:Option>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobPrintQualityAdjustment">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Standard"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobCopyPrevention">
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionText">
            <psf:Option>
                <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyPreventionTextString">
                    <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string">COPY</psf:Value>
                </psf:ScoredProperty>
                <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyPreventionFontSize">
                    <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">70</psf:Value>
                </psf:ScoredProperty>
            </psf:Option>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionTextFont">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:NimbusSans_Bold"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionTextPosition">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:Center">
                    <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyPreventionTextAngle">
                        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">30</psf:Value>
                    </psf:ScoredProperty>
                </psf:Option>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionTextType">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:UserDefined"/>
            </psf:Feature>
            <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionRepeatedText">
                <psf:Option name="ns0000:Repeat">
                    <psf:ScoredProperty name="ns0000:CopyPreventionLineSpace">
                        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">70</psf:Value>
                    </psf:ScoredProperty>
                </psf:Option>
            </psf:Feature>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionMaskType">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:None"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionPatternEffects">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Normal"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionColor">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Black"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:CopyPreventionDensity">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Middle"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PageWatermark">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobImageDirection">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Normal"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobEdgeToEdgePrint">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobSlipSheet">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Off"/>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:PrintOnSlipSheet">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:NotPrintOnSlipSheet"/>
        </psf:Feature>
        <psf:Feature name="ns0000:SlipSheetInputBin">
            <psf:Option name="ns0000:Tray1"/>
        </psf:Feature>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:PageMediaType">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:Standard_Recycled"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobColorProfileSelectObject">
        <psf:Option name="ns0000:SetAllObject"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:Feature name="psk:JobHolePunch">
        <psf:Option name="psk:None"/>
    </psf:Feature>
    <psf:ParameterInit name="pskv11:JobPasscodeString" xmlns:psf="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework">
        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">123456</psf:Value>
    </psf:ParameterInit>
    <psf:Feature name="pskv11:JobPasscode" xmlns:psf="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework">
        <psf:Option name="psk:On"/>
    </psf:Feature>
</psf:PrintTicket>
```

Comment: Did you check the printer logs and the print server logs?  Do other tickets print?  You probably have a schema issue and should check for schema errors.

Comment: Tickets without 
```<psf:ParameterInit name="pskv11:JobPasscodeString" xmlns:psf="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework">
        <psf:Value xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">123456</psf:Value>
    </psf:ParameterInit>
    <psf:Feature name="pskv11:JobPasscode" xmlns:psf="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework">
        <psf:Option name="psk:On"/>
    </psf:Feature>```
will print, Printerlogs I still have to look at, thanks for the tip

Comment: You mean the tickets print without the schemas?  Looks like you are using Microsoft Samples that have invalid schemas in the xml.

Comment: Here is link to latest schema document. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/printdocs/print-schema.md?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thanks for your further informations.
We found the solution:
If you can change the Value in JobRicPrintJob to RicPrintLocked
```<psf:Feature name="ns0000:JobRicPrintJob">
  <psf:Option name="ns0000:RicPrintLocked"/>
 </psf:Feature>```
Then it works like charm :-)